# password-confirmation doesn't work after changing password field name in laravel

Tags: laravel

I change my authentication table to "students" table with column name on my database "Password" and also change password field name on register blade to "Password" and same thing for email, its "Email" instead of "email" for both database and form field, everything was okay before i add validate to my controller like this:

```
    $this->validate($request, [

        'Email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:students',
        'Password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
```

when i remove this code from my controller everything works successfully, but when i add it and try to submit register form it shows me that the password confirmation does not match.

Answer (score 3):

You said you changed the password field and you also have confirmed validation so you also have to change password confirm field too

Here is a quote from laravel doc

> ### confirmed
>
> The field under validation must have a matching field of
> foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is
> password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in
> the input.

Comment: now it redirect me to the register form page without any message but with empty password and password confirmation fields!

Comment: I guess you need to share more of your code to see whats going on I cant shoot blind.

Answer (score 1):

The [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-confirmed) states:

> The field under validation must have a matching field of foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in the input.

So, you should be sure that an input field with name `Password_confirmation` exists so that the validation passes.

Comment: should i change something else? i rename the confirmation field as you said but now after i submit it redirect me to the register form page without any message but with empty password and password confirmation fields!